# ABP Framework, ConfigureByConvention not defined

Tags: abp

I'm following this tutorial https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-1?UI=NG&DB=EF#map-the-book-entity-to-a-database-table

In that step it instructs me to add `b.ConfigureByConvention` to the configuration in DbContext but `dotnet` tells me it is not defined.

I have abp version `5.3.4` and checked that the tutorial is for the correct version.
I generated the project with the abp CLI so the packages should not be a problem.

Is there some step that I overlooked?

The complete error is:

> 'EntityTypeBuilder' does not contain a definition for
> 'ConfigureByConvention' and no accessible extension method
> 'ConfigureByConvention' accepting a first argument of type
> 'EntityTypeBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ConfigureByConvention](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/blob/dev/framework/src/Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore/Volo/Abp/EntityFrameworkCore/Modeling/AbpEntityTypeBuilderExtensions.cs#L17-L31) method is an extension method, so your IDE probably could not find the related namespace and not suggested to you.

If you add **using Volo.Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.Modeling;** as namespace then it should work as expected.